# whats the difference between (App.Current as App).myValue and static myValue of App class?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

is there any difference between defining the variable as a static member in the App class like this:

```
public static string myValue;
//
string value = App.myValue;
```

and using the (App.Current as App) to retrieve the property of the App like this:

```
public string myValue { set; get; }
//
string value = (App.Current as App).myValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `App` is derived from `Application`, than almost no difference.

The small difference is at the very program beginning (in `Main`, for instance) `App.Current` is still `null`, whereas the static property will already be accessible. This is because the `Application` class is not a real singleton (or rather that `Current` doesn't trigger its creation -- this behaviour is at least for WPF 3.5).

The other small difference is of course that in the first case `myValue` is a field and not a property -- so some scenarios which expect properties (like binding etc.) would fail.